# Exit Bash Script to terminal

Tags: bash

Trying to get this script to display data, export to a file and then exit to the terminal. Script runs fine but won't exit. I have to hit the Ctrl+c every time. I've tried the commands kill, return, and exit with no success. Appreciate any advice. It's driving me crazy.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script that displays data about current directory.
echo

echo -n "Number of subdirectories in this directory: "
find . -type d | wc -l
sleep 2
echo

echo -n "List of files in the current directory: "
ls -1 | wc -l
sleep 2
echo

echo "List of zero-length files in current directory: "
find -size 0
sleep 2
echo

echo "Used storage space of the current directory is: "
du -sh
sleep 2
echo

echo -n "Data output of 'dirchk.sh' is in this directory called directory-check.results."

./dirchk.sh > directory-check.result
```

Answer (score 0):

If the current script is `dirchk.sh`, then it is going to run in an infinite loop. `dirchk.sh` runs `dirchk.sh`, which runs `dirchk.sh`... To avoid this, use the `tee` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script that displays data about current directory.
echo

echo -n "Number of subdirectories in this directory: "
(find . -type d | wc -l 2>&1) | tee directory-check.result
sleep 2
echo

echo -n "List of files in the current directory: "
(ls -1 | wc -l 2>&1) | tee -a directory-check.result
sleep 2
echo

echo "List of zero-length files in current directory: "
(find . -size 0 2>&1) | tee -a directory-check.result
sleep 2
echo

echo "Used storage space of the current directory is: "
(du -sh 2>&1) | tee -a directory-check.result
sleep 2
echo

echo -n "Data output of 'dirchk.sh' is in this directory called directory-check.results."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
[Command grouping](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands)
to avoid repeated `tee` calls

```sh
{
  set $(find . -type d | wc -l)
  echo "Number of subdirectories in this directory: $*"

  set $(ls -1 | wc -l)
  echo "List of files in the current directory: $*"

  set $(find -size 0)
  echo "List of zero-length files in current directory: $*"

  set $(du -sh)
  echo "Used storage space of the current directory is: $*"

  echo "Data output of 'dirchk.sh' is in this directory called"
  echo "directory-check.results."
} | tee directory-check.results
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Ok, I got the point. The error is at the end of the script that won't let you to exit. 
Can I suggest you using functions like this one?

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script that displays data about current directory.
echo
testing () {
echo "Number of subdirectories in this directory:  $(find . -type d | wc -l)"
sleep 2
echo

echo "List of files in the current directory: $(ls -1 | wc -l)"
sleep 2
echo

echo "List of zero-length files in current directory: $(find -size 0)"
sleep 2
echo

echo "Used storage space of the current directory is: $(du -sh)"
sleep 2
echo
}

testing 2>&1 |tee directory-check.results && echo  "Data output of dirchk.sh is in this directory called directory-check.results." 
exit
```